# How can I make <depends> an OR clause?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml

I got a menu option in adminhtml that must be visible if one or both of the children are enabled.

I tried something like that in the **adminhtml.xml** file:

```
<social_menu>
    ...
    <children>
        <facebook>
            ...
            <depends>
                <config>option A in config</config>
            </depends>
        </facebook>
        <twitter>
            ...
            <depends>
                <config>option B in config</config>
            </depends>
        </twitter>
    </children>
    <depends>
        <config>option A in config</config>
        <config>option B in config</config>
    </depends>
</social_menu>
```

The thing is that this works as an AND clause and I want to make it work as an OR.
Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is adminhtml.xml or system.xml?

Comment: This is the adminhtml.xml for show menu option on admin menu bar. The 'option A...','option B..' are yes/no on config.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849616/can-a-magento-adminhtml-field-depend-on-more-then-one-field-or-value

Comment: Thanks for the contribution @KonradSiamro but this still work as AND clause not OR. What is solutioned in the link has been implemented yet and works as the code example of my question. Anyway thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure I get Your issue. If the problem is with display one or two option You have 4 possibilities generally: No option display, Option A display, Option B display, Option A and B display. Depends on configuration on config (yes/no for option A and B) - right?

Comment: Right! The thing is now only display with option A and B and not with A or B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround and dirty solution but it does the trick.

The thing is use an observer at save config and then check the options values if any of them is enabled save in config the value for display, and check it on adminhtml.xml

**adminhtml.xml**

```
<social_menu>
    ...
    <children>
        <facebook>
            ...
            <depends>
                <config>[mymodule]/social_networks_group/link_facebook_enable</config>
            </depends>
        </facebook>
        <twitter>
            ...
            <depends>
                <config>[mymodule]/social_networks_group/link_twitter_enable</config>
            </depends>
        </twitter>
    </children>
    <depends>
        <config>[mymodule]/social_networks_group/display_menu</config>
    </depends>
</social_menu>
```

**config.xml**

```
<admin_system_config_changed_section_[mymodule]>
    <observers>
        <display_menu>
             <class>[mymodule]/adminhtml_observer</class>
             <method>display_menu</method>
        </display_menu>
    </observers>
</admin_system_config_changed_section_[mymodule]>
```

**Observer.php**

```
public function display_menu()
{
    $display = false;
    $optionA = Mage::getStoreConfig('[mymodule]/social_networks_group/link_facebook_enable');
    $optionB = Mage::getStoreConfig('[mymodule]/social_networks_group/link_twitter_enable');
    if ($optionA or $optionB) {
        $display = true;
    }
    Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('[mymodule]/social_networks_group/display_menu', $display);
}
```

If anyone think in other simple solution, it will be apreciated.
Hope this will be useful for someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<social_menu>
    ...
    <depends>
        <config separator='|'>option A in config|option B in config</config>
    </depends>
</social_menu>
```